# Symfony 3 Doctrine How to build query without columns index suffix

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I've table like: *product_id->name,description, price*

I want to retrieve all products, so this is my code for retrieve products

```
    $doc = $this->getDoctrine();
    $em = $doc->getEntityManager();
    $conn = $em->getConnection();
    $repo = $doc->getRepository('AppBundle:Products');
    $query = $repo->createQueryBuilder('p')->getQuery();
    $sql = $query->getSql();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $products = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Problem is when building a query it's always add column index suffix after column name as alias

So results is going to be like:

```
[
    {"product_id_0":"1","name_1":"Name1","description_2":"Desc1","price_3":"100"},
    {"product_id_0":"2","name_1":"Name2","description_2":"Desc2","price_3":"200"}
]
```

Notice their are suffix like _0, _1 after column name that I don't want it,
How can I build query without alias like that?

Comment: Replace your last for lines with $query->fetchArray.  Better yet, use fetchAll and work with objects.  http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html

Comment: @Cerad Their is no method named fetchArray in class Doctrine\ORM\Query and Doctrine\DBAL\Statement.

Comment: I typed too fast.  $query->getArrayResult(). http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats

Comment: Thanks, I've another question...
if I would like to get real column that I defined like product_id instead of productId how can I do that?

Comment: I don't think you have quite grasped the concept of an Object Relational Manager.  Sounds like you want to work at the sql level which is fine.  Take a look at Doctrine's Database Access Layer: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/

Comment: Seems like I have to use function like $conn->prepare($sql); and $conn->execute(); right?

I hope it provides a convenient way than this because I am making web-service for the client which require real column name.

Comment: There is nothing actually stopping you from having your object property names match database table column names.  Camel case is the convention but using all lower case with underscores will work.

Answer (score 0):

You've already got a repository.

When you have a repository, you do not need to create raw SQL queries or even use the created ones. Let Doctrine take care of that (this is the DBAL, Doctrine's database abstraction layer).

Instead, use a method like `findAll()` or `findBy()` to get objects.

Example:

```
$repo = $doc->getRepository('AppBundle:Products');
$results = $repo -> findAll();

// Returns array(Product, Product, ...), which should be mapped to an entity
// so that you can use $product -> getName() or whatever you need.
```

You can also create a query to get an array result:

```
$results = $repo -> createQueryBuilder('p') -> getQuery() -> getArrayResult();
```

Documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Comment: Thanks, I've another question...
if I would like to get real column that I defined like product_id instead of productId how can I do that?